# Sum up all integers imported from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to web scrape with python. I've been trying to add all the integers imported but can't seem to find a way to do it.

Here's the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
source = requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=iphone+xr&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=iphone+xr+128+gb&_sacat=0').text
soup =BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for post in soup.find_all("li",{"class" : "s-item"}):
   price = post.find_all("span", {"class" : "s-item__price"})[0].text
   price2 = price.strip( '$' )
   price3 = price2.replace(",", "")
   price4 =price3[0:5]
   price5 = float(price4)
   price6 = round(price5)
   print(price6)
```

It prints:

```
1130
1226
1130
1100
870
17
1433
1089
652
944
728
575
740
610
730
882
760
530
660
958
750
588
730
730
645
754
750
750
361
909
332
751
750
746
550
773
831
888
750
922
939
927
485
680
1250
888
1117
650
775
600
```

Basically what I want to do is add that all up into one number.

Comment: could you edit your indentation so we know what is supposed to be in the for loop, and what isn't?

Comment: I just edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer. You need to declare a variable before for loop and initialize with 0 and use that variable in the loop to sum up the price values and finally outside the loop, print the total summed up values. That's all.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from lxml import etree
source = requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=iphone+xr&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=iphone+xr+128+gb&_sacat=0').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
total_price = 0
for post in soup.find_all("li",{"class" : "s-item"}):
  price = post.find_all("span", {"class" : "s-item__price"})[0].text
  price2 = price.strip( '$' )
  price3 = price2.replace(",", "")
  price4 = price3[0:5]
  price5 = float(price4)
  price6 = round(price5)
  total_price = total_price + price6
print("Sum price is: %d"%(total_price))
```

Comment: I applied the changes and I got an error. It  says:

  File "scrape.py", line 15
    print("Sum price is: %d"%(total_price))
                                          ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Look, there seems to be an indentation issue with the copied code. Please try to manually indent the lines after the for loop.

Comment: Hey thanks it worked! But I was just wondering if I wanted to only display the last part of the addition, like the final sum, how would I do that? For example I want to just display the final digit which is 39205.

Comment: What do you mean by final price? Is it just the total summed up values that you are asking to be displayed? Then in that case the program posted above is doing the same. I have removed the print statement in the for-loop which was displaying each price earlier, instead I have put a single print() outside the loop to display the sum total price.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, you could rewrite all the steps in your loop as a separate function:

```
def get_price(post):
       price = post.find_all("span", {"class" : "s-item__price"})[0].text
       price2 = price.strip( '$' )
       price3 = price2.replace(",", "")
       price4 =price3[0:5]
       price5 = float(price4)
       price6 = round(price5)
       return price6
```

Now the loop you have can be rewritten as

```
for post in soup.find_all("li",{"class" : "s-item"}):
    print(get_price(post))
```

What's the point you ask? Well, Python's built-in `sum` function has an interface that lets you pass in a generator like this:

```
sum(get_price(post) for post in soup.find_all("li",{"class" : "s-item"}))
```

Or equivalently:

```
sum(map(get_price, soup.find_all("li",{"class" : "s-item"})))
```

You can rewrite your function as a one-liner:

```
def get_price(post):
       return round(float(post.find_all("span", {"class" : "s-item__price"})[0].text.strip('$').replace(',', '')[:5]))
```

This won't make your code any more legible, but you could avoid writing a separate function here by using the equivalent expression:

```
sum(round(float(post.find_all("span", {"class" : "s-item__price"})[0].text.strip('$').replace(',', '')[:5])) for post in soup.find_all("li",{"class" : "s-item"}))
```